# R find the correct name with conditions

Tags: r

I have following data `data <- data.frame(names = c("ALBERT | ALBERTOS | ALBERT 2","PIERRE | PIERRE 2 | PIERRE_SECOND | PIERRE_SECOND 2"))`

I want to apply conditions on it to find the correct name for each row.

-> First condition: Frequency: "ALBERT" appears 2 times so the first row must return "ALBERT"

-> Second condition: the longest string: "PIERRE" and  "PIERRE_SECOND" appear 2 times so I want to keep "PIERRE_SECOND".

I start by spliting strings of each row with separator "\|" : 
`data$names <- as.character(data$names); data2 <- strsplit(data$names,"\\|")`

and I don't know what's my next step.

do you have an idea?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: can you show the expected output

Comment: @akrun , I expect following output ```data_solution <- data.frame(names = c("ALBERT", "PIERRE_SECOND"))```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(stringr)
data %>% 
  mutate(rn = row_number()) %>% 
  separate_rows(names, sep="\\s*\\|\\s*") %>%
  mutate(names = str_remove(names, "\\s+\\d+$")) %>%
  add_count(rn, names) %>% 
  group_by(rn) %>%
  slice(which.max(n))
```

Comment: thank you, I think your proposition is not far. the second row should return "PIERRE_SECOND":  because it appears 2 times as "PIERRE" but it's a longer name than "PIERRE".  (The second condition apply after the first one)

Comment: based on what akrun propose I add ```arrange()``` function, it works in this case. I gonna apply this on my  thousands lines and see how it works. THANK YOU!                    ```data %>% 
  mutate(rn = row_number()) %>% 
  separate_rows(names, sep="\\s*\\|\\s*") %>%
  mutate(names = str_remove(names, "\\s+\\d+$")) %>%
  add_count(rn, names) %>%
  mutate(nbre_char = nchar(names)) %>%
  arrange(desc(nbre_char)) %>%
  group_by(rn) %>% 
  slice(which.max(n)) ```